# k2 extension not showing in joomla component

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

k2 (version2.6.9) extension is not showing / displaying in joomla 3.4.4 and  > admin > components.
But I can access via URL `index.php?option=com_k2`

Any help?

Comment: did you  check its XML file?

Comment: Not yet, which XML file did you mean?

Comment: what if you check -> extensions -> manage extensions -> search "K2"? you should see a list containing references to the component itself and various modules.

Comment: @Grafficode 
_Yes, i checked this extensions -> manage extensions -> search "K2"
And found out the "N/A folder",  that stranged.

this is the result:
  
  
K2 Comments 
  
K2 Content 
  
K2 Quick Icons (admin) 
  
K2 Stats (admin) 
  
K2 Tools
  
K2 Users
 
It is the caused for this issue @Gafficode?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall K2 and then re-install it. Make sure you backup your database and your filesystem first. The reason for having this problem is because of a small corruption in the backend's menu (possibly due to some issues post updating the Joomla website).

Comment: Haven't uninstall the k2 extension yet, however i did re-install k2 and get error message.